# Modifying the definition of iso/automorphism of a formal language string found in Eugene Luk's and Laszlo Babai's works...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, formal-languages, automorphism-group

Reference article: https://jeremykun.com/tag/automorphism-groups/

In Eugene Luk's and Laszlo Babai's work on the graph isomorphism problem, they rely fundamentally on isomorphisms of strings.  But they merely define an isomorphism of two equal-length strings $x,y$ to be a permutation $\sigma \in S_{|x|}$ such that $x_{\sigma (i)} = y_i$, where $x = x_1 \cdots x_n$ sim $y$.

I would like a definition that also incorperates alphabetical changes (permutations?).  So for instance $x = abcdefabc$ has the automorphism sending $a \mapsto d$ and at the same time maps the index where $a$ resides to the index where $d$ resides.  So that $(a,d)$ "together with" $(1,4)$ forms a basic example of an automorphism of $x$.

So what construction of group theory would accomplish this in terms of strings?

The point is that $abc$ and $def$ are isomorphic as strings, but $abc$ and $dee$ are not.  I'm not sure how this works group theoretically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the string automorphism problem, we're allowed to specify any group $G$ acting on our strings, not just the symmetric group, and ask: is there an element of $G$ that takes one string to the other?

To take advantage of this, if our alphabet has $n$ letters, replace the $i^{\text{th}}$ letter by a block $00\dots 1 \dots 00$ of length $n$, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ symbol is $1$ and the rest are $0$. For example, if the alphabet is $(a,b,c)$ and $n=3$, the string $abacab$ would be represented as $100\,010\,100\,001\,100\,010$.

Now let $G$ be the permutation group generated by the following permutations:

1. Swap the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ block entirely, for some $i$ and $j$.
2. In *every* block, swap the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ symbol.

For example, we can swap the $3^{\text{rd}}$ and $6^{\text{th}}$ blocks in $100\,010\,100\,001\,100\,010$ to get $100\,010\,010\,001\,100\,100$, which corresponds to $abbcaa$; this is the ordinary permutation of strings we were already allowed. (If we wanted only some permutations of our strings, then we can limit the type-1 permutations to only the ones we like.)

We can also swap the $2^{\text{nd}}$ and $3^{\text{rd}}$ symbol in every block, turning $100\,010\,100\,001\,100\,010$ into $100\,001\,100\,010\,100\,001$; back in Letterland, this corresponds to turning $abacab$ into $acabac$, or swapping $b$ with $c$. In general, swapping the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ symbol in every block is equivalent to swapping the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ letter in our alphabet.

Comment: Can you write this in terms of $\sigma : \Sigma \simeq \Sigma$ and also a permutation $\tau$ of our string indices?  And I'm not seeing the point of re-encoding into binary.  Also, note that I'm not working on the string automorphism problem per-se and especially not specifically their instance of it: given some group of permutations $G$.  I'm just asking about the definition itself.

Comment: I *am* writing this in terms of a permutation of the string indices. That is what I am doing. The point of re-encoding into binary is so that I can write the alphabet change in terms of a permutation of the string indices.

Comment: Also, I don't like the binary encoding.  My alphabet is going to be too huge for this to be feasible.  Think visible ASCII or even Unicode.  If every symbol takes up 128 binary digits conservatively, then there's no way I can work on a whole textbook of text!

Comment: If your alphabet is huge but only some permutations of it are allowed, then you might be able to get away with a more efficient encoding. Anyways, if you want a more general definition of "string-alphabet isomorphism" that allows for such changes, then you can just make that definition. My answer is to explain how the problem you describe can be reduced to the string isomorphism problem.

Comment: If your goal is computational efficiency, one option is to go backwards and replace your string isomorphism problem by a graph isomorphism problem, which you can then solve with one of many graph isomorphism solvers out there. I can expand on this in my answer if you like.

Comment: I don't like that approach.  I think I need to work in terms of strings / formal language morphisms, because I want to end up defining an automorphism of a CFG (grammar).  Do you know how one would do _that_?   I like how Graph Isomorphism depends upon string isomorphism because the latter seems more fundamental.

Comment: The idea of my post is this.  $s = abcabcdefdef$ has within it two "isomorphic copies" of the smallest grammar problem (single-string grammars, though I'm interested in general CFG problem).  So solve it once, and apply the correct permutation of letters / positions and you get the second one free.  Within a big body of text, this will lead to more efficiency, because it's like memoizing isomorphic subproblems that have already been solved.  Applications: data compression, grammar inference.  This assumes you can solve the smallest grammar problem exactly, by solving certain smaller subproblem